# Sequence integrity check documents in mongodb & python

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have three documents from Transaction collection, in each document there are amount and walletCredit . I want to check that the sum of value of amount and walletCredit, shoud be the value of next one walletCredit .

here is my documents:

[image]

now I can do this but it is not complete:

```
pipeline = [
        {
            "$match": {
                "status": 1,
                "walletId": 1
            }

        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$walletId",
                "total": {"$sum": "$amount"},
            }
        }
    ]

    transPerWalletId = Transaction.objects.aggregate(*pipeline)

    for items in transPerWalletId:
       
        transactions = Transaction.objects(walletId=items['_id'])

        for transaction in transactions:
            tmp = transaction.walletCredit + transaction.amount
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: so you want to check sum of amount and walletcredit is same as forth doc ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi , I want to check if sum of amount and walletCredit of the first Doc, is the same as the value of walletCredit of second Doc(next doc). and do this in sequence for all docs